# Using Bacon.js with FlightJS

Tags: javascript, bacon.js, twitter-flight

Is Bacon compatible with Twitter's Flight? I saw this talk where they are apparently being used together (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0N1NdE-9u0) but couldn't get a minimal example to work.

This is my flight component with traditional event handling alongside Bacon's event stream.
The latter just logs `undefined` for the `data.a` and it turns out what's being passed to the function registered with `onValue` is actually the event object (named `e` in the traditional handler function) with no access to the data object.

```
define(function (require) {
  'use strict';
  var c = require('flight/lib/component'),
    $ = require('jquery'),
    B = require('bacon');
  $.fn.asEventStream = B.$.asEventStream;
  return c(f);

  function f() {
    this.after('initialize', function () {
      // traditional handler
      this.on('dummyData', function (e, data) {
        console.log('jquery: ' + data.a);
      });
      // Bacon handler
      this.$node.asEventStream('dummyData').onValue(function (data) {
        console.log('bacon: ' + data.a);
      });
      // emit data object
      this.trigger('dummyData', { a: 'b' });
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an optional argument to asEventStream function that you can use to map the event payload:

```
  this.$node.asEventStream('dummyData', function(e, data) {
     return data;
  }).onValue(function (data) {
    console.log('bacon: ' + data.a);
  });
```

Take a look at the examples here: https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#%24-aseventstream